# Segurança em verificar e validar usuário com PDO:PHP

Tags: php, pdo, segurança, validação, login

Estou querendo criar um painel com um ambiente seguro para login, utilizando o PDO como forma de validação.

Para explicar, estou usando o banco de dados do IPB fórum, basicamente quero aproveitar o mesmo usuário do fórum e criar um ambiente para o membro registrado em meu forum acessar novas funcções, e aqui vai o código:

**database.php**

```
// HOST MYSQL - FORUM IPB
$host_ipb="127.0.0.1";
$db_ipb="forum";
$user_ipb="root";
$userpass_ipb="root";
try {
$con_ipb = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_ipb;dbname=$db_ipb",$user_ipb,$userpass_ipb,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**functions.php**

function login($con_ipb, $email, $senha){

```
/* Verificando o members_pass_salt do email solicitado */
$dados_email=array(':email'=>$email);
$p_query_email = $con_ipb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ipb_core_members WHERE email=:email");
$p_query_email->execute($dados_email);
$usuario_email = $p_query_email->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($usuario_email as $usuario_email2) { 
        $members_pass_salt = $usuario_email2->members_pass_salt;
        }

/* Conversão da senha para members_pass_hash do IPB */
$members_pass_hash = crypt( $senha, '$2a$13$' . $members_pass_salt );  

/* Fazendo checagem de email e senha(members_pass_hash) e autorizando a sessão */
$dados_user_pass=array(':email'=>$email,':members_pass_hash'=>$members_pass_hash);
$p_query_verifica = $con_ipb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ipb_core_members WHERE email=:email and members_pass_hash=:members_pass_hash");
$p_query_verifica->execute($dados_user_pass);
$email_senha = $p_query_verifica->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$error_data = false;
if ($email_senha) {
    ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
    $_SESSION["email_senha"]=$email_senha;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    header("Location:dashboard.html");
        }else{  
    header("Location:error.html");      
        }}
```

**verificar.php**

```
require_once('configs/functions.php');
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
echo login($con_ipb, $email, $senha).PHP_EOL;
```

Está funcional, sem erros. A minha dúvida é se está seguro para ser usado num ambiente seguro sem possibilidades de SQL injection.

Obrigado!

Comment: Possível duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864

Comment: Onde estaria essa possível duplicata?

Comment: Acredito que @GuilhermeCostamilam  não queria dizer duplicata e sim te passar um post que fala sobre prevenir sql injection

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo entendo, só que realmente ainda estou aprendendo sobre programação de php com pdo, e não consigo ver problemas, mesmo eu lendo os links que ele enviou. Preciso de um olhar de outro programador mais experiente.

Comment: Já leu esse https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php#security.database.avoiding